# Permissioning Dataflow to read a BigQuery table that is pointing to Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

BigQuery can read from Google Drive as a federated source. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources). I want to be able to read a table in BigQuery into my Dataflow pipeline that is pointing to a Drive document.

Hooking up BigQuery to the file in Drive works perfectly fine:

[image]

But, when I then try to read that table into my Dataflow pipeline I (understandably) get the following error:

> No suitable credentials found to access Google Drive. Contact the
>   table owner for assistance.

```
[..]
PCollection<TableRow> results = pipeline.apply("whatever",
BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery("SELECT * from [CPT_7414_PLAYGROUND.google_drive_test]"))
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
[..]
```

How do I permission Dataflow to be able to read from a table in BigQuery that is pointing to Drive?

Comment: You can read some details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756157/queries-done-in-sheets-pulling-from-bigquery-permissions-help-needed . As I understand you need to ask for Drive permissions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow does not currently support reading from a federated table backed by Drive, but this is coming soon.

Comment: Bummer. Got a rough idea of when we can expect it? It would help our business users out a lot.